# ASP:BoundField headerText as variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to dynamically set the HeaderText property on ASP:BoundField using a variable?

I have an ascx control which is used in two places that checks the current request path to see if it should use one string or another for the HeaderText value

```
<%  
    var headerTextVal = "Top";
    var path = Page.Request.Path;
    if (!path.Contains("/desktop/homescreen.aspx"))
    {
        headerTextVal = "T";
    }
%>

<asp:GridView ID="summaryGridView" DataSourceID="MySummary" runat="server"
    Visible="true" EnableViewState="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="name, top"
    Width="100%" AllowSorting="true" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="summaryGridView_RowDataBound"
    OnRowCommand="summaryGridView_RowCommand" OnSorting="summaryGridView_Sorting">
    <Columns> 
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="top" HeaderText="<%#Eval("headerTextVal")%>" SortExpression="top" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I try it like this I get the following error:

> ASP.Net Runtime error: Code blocks are not supported in this context

Is it not possible to do it like this?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void summaryGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        if(your condition)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "T";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, so that means that I have to make the change in the code behind file rather than the .ascx file itself? Can you explain why its not possible to use dynamic variables on the ascx file?

Comment: Great Example. Saves my time. Thanks